# Polynomial of odd degree

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

How to show that a real valued odd degree polynomial agrees at least at one point with a real valued bounded continuous function???
I seem to be clueless here..please somebody help

Comment: Use the intermediate value theorem and the behavior of odd-degree polynomials at $\pm\infty$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x$ and $g(x_0)<-M$ for some $x_0$ and $g(x_1)>M$ for some $x_1$, what can you say about the function $f(x)-g(x)$ at $x_0$ and $x_1$? Now if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous?

Comment: I could certainly say that g has a root between the $x_o$ and $x_1$ but nothing about the difference

Comment: Really, you can't say anything about $f(x_0)-g(x_0)$, nor $f(x_1)-g(x_1)$? Hint: I chose $x_0,x_1$ pretty carefully...

Comment: Thnx thomas for the help

Answer (score 3):

If $f(x) = (ax^n + \text{lower-degree terms})$ and $a>0$ then as $x\to\infty$ the leading term $ax^n$ overwhelms the lower-degree terms and so $f(x)\to+\infty$.  As $x\to -\infty$ you get $f(x)\to-\infty$, and that's where you need the fact that $n$ is odd.  If $n$ were even you'd have $f(x)\to+\infty$.

Now take $f(x)-g(x)$ where $g$ is your bounded function.  Since $g$ is bounded, $f(x)-g(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$ and $f(x)\to-\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$.

And if $a<0$, just change signs where appropriate.

Finally: Cite the fact that $f$ and $g$ are continuous so you can use the intermediate value theorem to show that since  $f-g$ is unbounded in both directions, it must be $0$ somewhere.

Comment: Thanx michael hardy .i am new to this community but the little i have followed let me tell you ive become a fan of yours

Comment: @user312254 : Thank you. $\qquad$